# Switch Statement with Array condition

Tags: c, switch-statement

I am having an impossible time trying to make this work. It is just a sample run of the code without the full options.

What is needed from the program is for the user to enter there choice, 1-3 or a-c. I am using a string in case the user enters more than just a single character. The switch case then should compare just the first char in the array to the cases. And the do while loop is to make sure it keeps going until they enter the right characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 81

void main(){
    char thing[SIZE] = {3};
    int rvalue;
    do
    {
        scanf_s("%s", thing);
        switch (thing[0])
        {
        case 'a':
        case 1:
            printf("first\n");
            rvalue = 1;
            break;
        case 'b':
        case 2:
            printf("second\n");
            rvalue = 2;
            break;
        case 'c':
        case 3:
            printf("third\n");
            rvalue = 3;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Wrong\n");
            rvalue = 4;
            break;
        }
    } while (rvalue == 4);
}
```

Comment: [`scanf_s()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) doesn't work like that. You must specicy the string size. Always check the return value, I/O can fail!

Comment: Just change `scanf_s("%s", thing);` to `scanf_s("%s", thing, SIZE);`.

Comment: Always tell your compiler to show all warnings possible and take them for serious.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
scanf_s("%s", thing);
```

To

```
scanf_s("%s", thing,(unsigned int)sizeof(thing)); //Read the comments to know why the cast is required
```

This done because `scanf` and `scanf_s` are different function. `scanf_s` has an additional argument present to prevent [buffer overflows](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).
Also change these

```
case 1:
case 2:
case 3:
```

To

```
case '1':
case '2':
case '3':
```

Because the character 1(`'1'`) and the rest of them are different from the integer 1. The characters(those enclosed in single quotes) have their values represented in the [ASCII table](http://benborowiec.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/better_ascii_table.jpg).

Comment: The result of `sizeof` is of type `size_t`, but MS `scanf_s()` expects `unsigned int` (C11 expects `rsize_t`).

Comment: @cremno , Dosen't `size_t` have type `unsigned int`?

Comment: No, it can be any unsigned integer type. For example, your code is broken on Windows x64 where `sizeof(unsigned int)` is 4, but `sizeof(size_t)` is 8.

Comment: @cremno , I see. So, would casting the result of `sizeof` to `unsigned int` work?

Comment: Of course (I know it's ugly. I also don't know why the person behind `scanf_s()` decided to use `unsigned int`.)

Answer (score 1):

As far as it seems, you want to print `first` when the first character in the `thing` string is `a` or `1`, and so on.

The problem is that `case 1:` is **not same** as `case '1':`. `1` is an `int`, `'1'` is a `char`, and as you are comparing the first *character* of the string, you need to change your `case`statements a bit.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 81

void main(){
    char thing[SIZE] = {3};
    int rvalue;
    do
    {
        scanf_s("%s", thing,SIZE);
        switch (thing[0])
        {
        case 'a':
        case '1':
            printf("first\n");
            rvalue = 1;
            break;
        case 'b':
        case '2':
            printf("second\n");
            rvalue = 2;
            break;
        case 'c':
        case '3':
            printf("third\n");
            rvalue = 3;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Wrong\n");
            rvalue = 4;
            break;
        }
    } while (rvalue == 4);
}
```